# How to convert string to boolean multiple condition in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, conditional-statements, laravel-8

How to convert string to conditional `boolean`

example string with boolean condition.

```
$condition1 = 'false || ( true && false)'; // should return false
$condition2 = 'false || true';  // should return true
$condition3 = 'true && false';  // should return false
$condition4 = 'true && (true || false);  // should return true
```

I tried these codes but not working..

```
$result =  (boolean) $condition1;
$result = filter_var($condition1, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
$result = settype($condition1, 'boolean');
```

is there a way to convert it?

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is the purpose of this? If you're hardcoding some logical expressions, you might as well hardcode their result into the variable.

Comment: Write your own parser for tokenizing true false with nested brackets to evaluate results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [php `eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function

```php
eval("\$status=true || false; return \$status;")
```

In your case

```php
eval('\$condition1 = false || ( true && false);');
eval('\$condition2 = false || true;');
// And so on ...
```

Comment: eval function is a critical for security, is there another way ?